# Send email in android 4.1 and more

Tags: android, email, send

I'm using code from a previous Stack Overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/2695686)

It is working perfectly in android 2.2 , 2.3

But it don't work on 4.1 and above -  anyone help me how to fix it?

Error report

```
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510): ERROR
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:365)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.getLocalAddress(InternetAddress.java:517)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at javax.mail.internet.UniqueValue.getUniqueMessageIDValue(UniqueValue.java:99)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateMessageID(MimeMessage.java:2054)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2076)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2042)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:117)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at hai.bt.expensemanager.Mail.send(Mail.java:77)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at hai.bt.expensemanager.ForgotPasswordActivity$2.onClick(ForgotPasswordActivity.java:79)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4874)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
08-19 16:18:23.722: E/SEND(17510):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: are you getting any exceptions? the catlog would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet:

```
// mail function
    private void mail() {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("message/rfc822");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] { "abc@xyz.in" });
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ENQUERY");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(ContactUsActivity.this,
                    "Email can't be sent due to device problem",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

It worked for me!

Most probably you are getting the error because you are not sending the email as an async task. ICS and above do not allow transactions in the main thread!

Comment: Thank, but i want to send email in background

Comment: This you did not mention in your question............

Comment: Thank kittu88, my problem solved by Async task.

Comment: @haibtbk If you are satisfied with my suggestion then please accept the answer........